# Core audio - remove echo effect/reverberation

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, objective-c++

I have app which is supported by core audio framework. App records voice from mic and plays it out through headphones. When I am at big room I can hear "echo" effect sound. Is it in core audio some property (maybe core audio unit property) which can solve this problem? Or some framework? Thank you for ideas! ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your audio graph, try using the VoiceProcessingIO unit instead of the 'normal' RemoteIO unit.  The VoiceProcessingIO unit includes echo cancellation, gain control and some other features that should help in your situation.

Comment: I know about that but I think there's no effect. I can hear reverberation. But thanks for help.

Comment: In pure technical audio terminology, this is reverberation (not echo). To remove it you will need to implement a de-reverberation code that will sit immediately after getting the PCMs, and before the PCMs are encoded in whichever format you want. @Jonathan, the echo cancellation in mobile phones' speech/voice processing cannot handle reverberations. These echo cancellation software cancel only the so called echo sounds thats looping back into the mic from the phones speaker because of very close distance between them.